# What is a btrfs "5 disk RAID 10" (or raid 10 with odd number disks)?

Tags: btrfs, raid

In [this video](https://youtu.be/XwH4N4UEQbs?t=661) the author says he went from four disk BTRFS raid 10 array to a five disk RAID 10 and it took about a week. But I'm confused, how does a five disk RAID 10 work? Raid 10 is two or more sets of mirrors of (two drives) that are striped together. What does a five-drive RAID 10 mean?

Comment: btrfs' definition of "raid1" and "raid10" is non-standard.   (greatly simplified and glossing over many details) btrfs groups the disks together and achieves redundancy by having multiple copies of the files on multiple disks in the pool (i can't remember if btrfs is limited to two copies or is capable of more - zfs allows up to copies=3).   This is arguably better and more useful than traditional raid1/10 (especially since it allows for drives of different sizes) but it's certainly not the "mirrored drives" that most people think of when they hear the term.

Comment: I forgot to add this link yesterday - arstechnica published a good overview article about btrfs in Sep 2021: [Examining btrfs, Linux’s perpetually half-finished filesystem](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/examining-btrfs-linuxs-perpetually-half-finished-filesystem/).  Amongst other things, it describes how btrfs' raid-1 and raid-10 work.

Comment: @cas that's a pretty bad article that doesn't address this question, from my read.

Comment: @cas unrelated new question from the article  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752839/3285

Comment: Seems a pretty good article to me - it certainly matches my experience with btrfs (I experimented with it for around a year as a potential replacement for mdadm+XFS before deciding on ZFS back around 2010 - I lost data on btrfs arrays multiple times, fortunately only test copies of data I had on XFS...btrfs has improved since then, but data-loss is still one of the major complaints about it even today.  ZFS, by contrast has been rock-solid reliable which is the number one thing I want out of a filesystem)

Answer (score 3):

In Btrfs, "RAID" is chunk-level, not disk-level, so it's possible to have more than the regular number of disks because each of the 1GB chunks can be RAIDed to a different combination of disks.

I believe understanding how Btrfs 'raid1' works is the basis for understanding 'raid10'.

For example, the `raid1` profile doesn't mean the entire disk is mirrored – it means exactly "two copies of this chunk". Doesn't matter how many disks you actually have in the array, always **two** of them are selected to hold copies of any particular chunk: if you have a three-disk "raid1" filesystem, then one chunk might be duplicated to A+B, another to B+C, the next to A+C, and so on. (Likewise `raid1c3` means exactly three copies and `raid1c4` is exactly four.)

So, similarly to that, `raid10` means "two striped copies": for every new chunk, four disks are selected, one copy of that chunk is striped across two of the disks, and a second copy is striped across the other two. In your case the fifth disk is unused; when the *next* chunk is allocated, though, the fifth disk will most likely be chosen to hold it, and overall the filesystem should end up roughly balanced (i.e. you will likely have all possible combinations of 4 disks)

Microsoft's Storage Spaces "columns" [also work the same way](http://web.archive.org/web/20171106051700/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/11/21/deep-dive-pool-in-spaces-direct/) (the blog post has a [graphic](http://web.archive.org/web/20190322093442im_/https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/11/PoolsBlog-Gif3-SV.gif) to illustrate the layout).

### Why is the balance operation taking so long?

In the video, the disks are the same size (4 TB each). Let's assume the worst-case scenario of almost no space left on the btrfs filesystem before adding the 5th disk. (A small amount of free space is needed to run the balance operation.) This means that 16 TB of data need to be re-distributed by `btrfs filesystem balance` so that each disk holds roughly the same amount of data, i.e. 3.2 TB each. In principle, it should be possible to achieve this by copying 0.8 TB of each disk to the new disk but this would involve modifying each RAID10 set of chunks in place. Btrfs does not implement this and instead re-allocates each set to a new location on all selected disks until balance is achieved. This requires about 80% of data to be moved, i.e. about 12.8 TB of 16 TB.

Comment: With 6 or 7 disks, each btrfs RAID10 chunk uses 6 disks. After growing (btrfs device add) to 8 disks, each new btrfs RAID10 chunk uses 8 disks, so you can end up with a mixture of different size RAID10 chunks, here chunks with 3 GiB and 4 GiB of usable space respectively.