# What is the difference between BTRFS RAID1 and BTRFS RAID5 on 3+ devices?

Tags: btrfs, raid1, raid5

According to [*"Examining btrfs, Linux’s perpetually half-finished filesystem"*](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/examining-btrfs-linuxs-perpetually-half-finished-filesystem/), BTRFS RAID1 is said to be *"guaranteed redundancy—copies of all blocks will be **saved on two separate devices**"*. It goes on to say that with BTRFS on both RAID1 and RAID5 you can have devices of different sizes. You can also have more than 3 devices with both.

Assuming you have three disks, what is the difference in btrfs between RAID1 and RAID5? They both protect against failure of one drive in the array.

Comment: [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have 3 disks, that are 2 TB each.

- Raid 1 makes two copies so the per-device usable is 50%: `2 TB * 0.5 * 3 disks` ie **3 TB of usable storage**.
- Raid 5 makes one copy and stripes for parity to achieve single-disk redundancy providing for a utilization rate of `(DISKS-1)/DISKS`: `(3-1) / 3 * 2 TB` or **4 TB of usable storage**.

---

This seems very poorly documented everywhere, but I was able to figure out what was going on with the [btrfs disk usage calculator](https://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-usage/?c=1&slo=1&shi=100&p=1&dg=1&d=2000&d=2000&d=2000)

Comment: So this is just normal RAID1 and RAID5? Being BTRFS doesn't make it any different?

Comment: @muru afaik, there is no such thing as "normal raid1" for 3 disks. I've never heard of it anyway.

Comment: So the difference is that it's not on a disk level?

Comment: "normal raid1 for 3 disks" is that all three drives are identical mirrors of each other. Any two drives can die without losing the data. If the disks are the same size, the storage capacity is that of **one** of the disks. If they're different sizes, capacity is that of the smallest. Same with 4 or 5 or more drive raid-1, more redundancy, same capacity. That's kind of why raid-10 is popular, a striped (raid-0) array of raid-1 arrays - it provides 50% capacity (or less if the raid-1s have more than two disks each), good redundancy, good read performance.

Comment: Not all raid-1 implementations support more than two drives,  and not all support disks of different sizes (so manual partitioning is required to provide equal sized partitions).

Comment: So then to answer @muru, in "normal raid 1 for 3 disks" you have three mirrored drives identical to each other. If each disk is 2 TB, you have 2 TB of usable storage. Whereas, with BTRFS RAID 1, you have 3 TB of usable storage with a 3 disk array of 2 TB drives.